# WxPython select item

Tags: python-3.6, listctrl, wxpython

I want get value from selected item in list when I click a button, and post it in another list.

```
    self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(30,100), pos=(20,30),
                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                     )

    self.list_ctrl2 = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(200,300),pos=(60,200), style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)




    btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
    btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Get Column 0")
    btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label="select")


    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)
    btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getColumn)
    btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getSelection)


def add_line(self, event):
    line = "Line %s" % self.index
    self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(self.index, line)
    self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
    self.list_ctrl.SetItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
    self.index += 1

def getColumn(self, event):

    item = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(itemIdx=0, col=0)
    print (item.GetText())
    self.list_ctrl2.InsertItem(item)

def getSelection (self, event):
    item2=self.list_ctrl.GetNextSelected()
    self.list_ctrl2.InsertItem(item2)
```

I have try with GetItem, GetNextSelected. I have search on https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.ListCtrl.html#wx.ListCtrl.GetNextSelected
But I think I have a syntaxic problem and I didn't find

Comment: What the problem you have is ? Do you get some error ? You refer to a button but your code shows 3, as well as 3 methods. You may want to post a **minimal functional** code reproducing your problem. Please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer

define list :

```
self.userList = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel,pos=(50,200), size=(-1,500),style=wx.LC_REPORT)
```

Bind event :

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.addSendList, self.userList)
```

define event :

```
def AddSendList(self, evt):
    choice= self.userList.GetFirstSelected()
    item = self.userList.GetItem(itemIdx=choice, col=0)
    textItem=item.GetText()
    print(choice)
    print(textItem)
    self.sendList.InsertItem(0,textItem)
```

With this Function I can have the selected value in a ListCtrl, and put value in a other ListCtrl.